# How to replicate a Visual Tree without using XamlReader?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've got a Visual Tree that I want to replicate. Since DependencyObjects cannot be (and should NOT be) cloned, I would like to know a good way to generate another tree based on it, preserving the structure and copying all the properties of each node (or remapping if necessary).

How could I do it?

**EDIT:** I cannot use DataTemplates. In fact, this question is because I have to re-implement them in an Open Source Project that intends to be a cross-platform WPF.

Comment: Why aren't you using a DataTemplate ...?

Comment: I don't use WPF DataTemplates because... I'm building them! I mean, I'm building DataTemplates from scratch. In fact, this question is because I'm working on a OSS project called Perspex that is intended to be "the new WPF". It's cross-platform.